# OCTAVE .m file to execute in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, octave

my application is in C# MVC with framework 4.5.2 and want to run external file(.m) and get output from that and it is written in Octave.

Note: Output result is in a string, so I have to show that output in C# html page.

Algorithm is written in octave and also in algorithm excel file is there to read data and external parameters are also passing through C#.

I tried the things which is already posted, the main concern is that my application is hosted in azure cloud. So, I can not install octave in cloud.
Can you suggest me any other way that directly run external file(.m) with dynamic excel file and parameters.
I can show my code what I have done. Its work in local with all but I can not install Octave in Azure cloud..
I put my installed folder to root path on server but its also not working.

```
public Octave(string pathToOctaveBinaries, bool createWindow)
    {
        StartOctave(pathToOctaveBinaries, createWindow);
    }

private void StartOctave(string pathToOctaveBinaries, bool createWindow)
    {
        _ptob = pathToOctaveBinaries;
        cw = createWindow;
        this.OctaveEchoString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        OctaveProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        if (pathToOctaveBinaries[pathToOctaveBinaries.Length - 1] != '\\')
            pathToOctaveBinaries = pathToOctaveBinaries + "\\";
        pi.FileName = pathToOctaveBinaries + "octave-cli.exe";
        pi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pi.UseShellExecute = false;
        pi.CreateNoWindow = !createWindow;
        pi.Verb = "open";
        //
        pi.WorkingDirectory = ".";
        OctaveProcess.StartInfo = pi;
        OctaveProcess.Start();
        OctaveProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OctaveProcess_OutputDataReceived);
        OctaveProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        OctaveEntryText = ExecuteCommand(null);
    }

public string ExecuteCommand(string command, int timeout)
    {
        if (OctaveProcess.HasExited)
        {
            StartOctave(_ptob, cw);
            if (OctaveRestarted != null) OctaveRestarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        _exitError = false;

        Thread tmp = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkThread));
        tmp.Start(command);

        if (!tmp.Join(timeout))
        {
            tmp.Abort();
            throw new Exception("Octave timeout");
        }
        if (_exitError)
        {
            throw new Exception(_errorMessage);
        }
        return SharedBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

This above is Octave class file. Where I dynamically pass the path of .exe to be run as thread.

Controller Code:

```
Octave octave = new Octave(OctaveFilePath, false);
string fileData = result.Data.ToString();
fileData = fileData.Replace("#ExcelFilePath#", excelFilePath);
fileData = fileData.Replace("#ABCD#", historyData);
string rasp = octave.ExecuteCommand(fileData, 30000);
```

From here I get string and that I show into html page.

Comment: You cannot run an Octave file without Octave. I’m not sure what you’re asking here. Maybe translate the algorithm to C#?

Comment: Why can't you install Octave on Azure?

Comment: @Andy is this possible to installed Octave on Azure Cloud? Can you suggest me step by step?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Algorithm is often changed, so as per requirement I have to give solution dynamically run octave .m file algorithm and get output from it and that I have to show in C#.